# Why does long pressing Control key trigger Escape in KDE?

Tags: keyboard, kde

I recently switched from GNOME 3 to KDE 5, and I found myself accidentally pressing Escape when holding the left Control key. It does not happen under any other desktop environments. How do I stop k*whathever*d from doing that?

Comment: Does this occur in all of your apps? Just asking because for some apps like vim, which requires extensive use of the escape key, this might be considered a really Wizzy feature.

Comment: Yes, it occurs everywhere. I don't use Vim that intensively, and I doubt it would be a noticeable improvement due to the fact it requires a longer press (about a second).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### I am now officially an idiot.

I use [KSuperKey](https://github.com/hanschen/ksuperkey) to access KRunner faster. And while setting up my desktop I thoughtlessly copied this snippet from ksuperkey's README:

```
ksuperkey -e 'Control_L=Escape;Super_L=Alt_L|F2'
```

After I finally realized I have removed the first item so it looks this way:

```
ksuperkey -e 'Super_L=Alt_L|F2'
```

Problem solved.